# Discrepancy In PostGIS Transformation: 103761 to 900913 to 4326 vs 103761 to 4326

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, transform, postgis-3.0

## Overview

I'm using PostGIS 3.1 on PostgreSQL 12.14 and I'm facing an issue with GIS data transformation and I need some assistance in understanding the cause of a significant discrepancy between two transformation paths. Specifically, when I transform my data from the `103761` projection to `900913` and then to `4326`, the resulting coordinates are approximately 20km north of the transformation directly from `103761` to `4326`. I'm puzzled as to what could be causing this discrepancy and would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me resolve this issue.

To provide more context, here are the steps I'm following:

- Original data is in the `103761` projection.
- I first transform the data from `103761` to the `900913` then to the commonly used `4326` projection using `ST_Transform(ST_Transform(geom, 900913), 4326)`.
- The issue arises when comparing the final coordinates from the above transformation path (`103761` to `900913` to `4326`) with the coordinates obtained when directly transforming from `103761` to `4326`. The two sets of coordinates are significantly different, with the former being approximately 20km north of the latter. (`ST_Transform(geom, 4326)`).
- **This has been working as expected up until now.**

## Example

### Query

```
SELECT
    ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) AS "original103761",
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 900913)) AS "103761to900913",
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_Transform(geom, 900913), 4326)) AS "103761to900913to4326",
    ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) AS "103761to4326",
FROM points_table
WHERE id=1;
```

### Results

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|original103761                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| {                                                         |
|   "type": "Point",                                        |
|   "crs": {                                                |
|     "type": "name",                                       |
|     "properties": {                                       |
|       "name": "ESRI:103761"                               |
|     }                                                     |
|   },                                                      |
|   "coordinates": [                                        |
|     660720.860221713,                                     |
|     146635.906983451                                      |
|   ]                                                       |
| }                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|103761to900913                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| {                                                         |
|   "type": "Point",                                        |
|   "crs": {                                                |
|     "type": "name",                                       |
|     "properties": {                                       |
|       "name": "ESRI:900913"                               |
|     }                                                     |
|   },                                                      |
|   "coordinates": [                                        |
|     -10275493.35989097,                                   |
|     5459282.550656371                                     |
|   ]                                                       |
| }                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|103761to900913to4326                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-92.306327371,44.152191809]}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|103761to4326                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-92.306327371,43.960183476]}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

[image: Incorrect Left / Correct Right]

## Additional Info

Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

- I'm using PostGIS 3.1 on PostgreSQL 12.14.
- It's hosted on a managed AWS RDS instance.
- It has been working as expected until now.
- I'm aware of the `3857` projection but I have a legacy requirement on `900913`.
- I'm not seeing this issue when working with data in a different original projection (ie not `103761`).
- I have verified that the transformation parameters for each step are correctly applied.
- I have double-checked the source data and confirmed its accuracy.
- Going `103761` to `4326` to `900913` to `4326` results in a small but expected discrepancy. (`ST_Transform(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), 900913), 4326)` -> `{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-92.306327371,43.959874117]}`)
- The relevant `spatial_ref_sys` table entries are:

```
INSERT INTO public.spatial_ref_sys 
  (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text)
  VALUES (
    900913,
    'ESRI',
    900913,
    'PROJCS["Google_Maps_Global_Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],AUTHORITY["EPSG","900913"]]',
    '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs'
  );
INSERT INTO public.spatial_ref_sys
  (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text)
  VALUES (
    103761,
    'ESRI',
    103761,
'PROJCS["NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Olmsted_Feet",GEOGCS["GCS_NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Olmsted",DATUM["D_NAD_1983_HARN_Adj_MN_Olmsted",SPHEROID["S_GRS_1980_Adj_MN_Olmsted",6378481.425,298.257222100883,AUTHORITY["ESRI","107753"]],AUTHORITY["ESRI","106753"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["ESRI","104753"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",43.8338888888889],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-92.9166666666667],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",43.8833333333333],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",44.1333333333333],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",100000],UNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["ESRI","103761"]]',
    '+proj=lcc +lat_0=43.8338888888889 +lon_0=-92.9166666666667 +lat_1=43.8833333333333 +lat_2=44.1333333333333 +x_0=152400.30480061 +y_0=30480.0609601219 +a=6378481.425 +rf=298.257222100883 +units=us-ft +no_defs +type=crs');
INSERT INTO public.spatial_ref_sys
  (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, srtext, proj4text)
  VALUES (
    4326,
    'EPSG',
    4326,
    'GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]',
    '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs '
  );
```

## Conclusion

Considering the above, I'm seeking guidance to understand the potential causes of this discrepancy.

Are there any known issues or common pitfalls that could lead to such discrepancies in GIS data transformations?

Are there any specific considerations I should take into account when working with these particular projections?

Could this be the result of an minor upgrade on the RDS instance?

Comment: Could you confirm that the result is the same if you use EPSG:3857 instead of the fake code 900913 that nobody should use any more?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Replacing `900913` with `3857` results in consistent transformations. However, the target system uses `900913` and this has been working accurately until very recently. I'm wondering what would cause this to suddenly change and why there is such a discrepancy in the transform paths.

Comment: If possible, could you also list the original coordinates before the transform? (Or is that already listed above?)

Comment: You might check to see what QGIS thinks is the definition of 900913. A 20 km north-south offset suggests that it's changed from using the spherical Mercator equations to the ellipsoidal ones or the GeodCRS in 900913 has changed.

Comment: Sorry, what "PostGIS", not QGIS, thinks the definition of 900913 is.

Comment: @Mintx Thank you for responding. I've added the original coordinates to the query example above.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you for responding. This transform was working fine until very recently. It's running on a manage RDS instance, is it possible that the change you suggested could have occurred from a minor version upgrade of PostGIS?

Comment: Why not use 3857? 900913 is not a real EPGS code so will probably not be supported at some stage, maybe now. If you need to set it to 900913 you can still use 3857 for the transformation: st_setsrid(st_transform(geom, 3857), 900913)

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto Thank you for responding. I'm already doing something along these lines to mitigate the issue. The purpose of the post is not about how to do things differently but to find what happened in this scenario. As the process worked perfectly well until very recently and I don't know why the situation has changed. I'm also trying to figure out if this can suddenly happen to other projections in the future.